# How can I put 1 date into 2 input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to put start date as final date of final date column if user doesn't select final date when form submit. my code is below.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="control-label">{!!Lang::get('site_lang.start_date')!!}</label>
    <input id="startDate" style="width:80%;" name="start_date" autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="control-label">{!!Lang::get('site_lang.end_date')!!}</label>
    <input id="endDate" style="width:80%;"  name="end_date" autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
 $('#startDate').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        format: '{{config('app.date_format_js')}}',
        maxDate: function () {
            return $('#endDate').val();
        }
    });

    $('#endDate').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
        format: '{{config('app.date_format_js')}}',
        minDate: function () {
            return $('#startDate').val();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery ui datepicker

Two way you can set end Date

```js
$('#startDate').datepicker();
$('#endDate').datepicker();

// Set End date on click submit button if end date is empty set end date value as start date 
// then submit form

$("#submit").click(function(){
      if(!$("#endDate").val()){
          var startDate = $("#startDate").val()
          $("#endDate").val(startDate)
      }
      $("#form").submit()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="">
        <input id="startDate"  name="start_date" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input id="endDate"  name="end_date" autocomplete="off"/>
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: by this method it's working but I want to show user final date just after the start date selection for his satisfaction, altField is not working for that so is there any other method ?

Comment: If user selected today date in start date then show next day in end date. right?

Comment: no no, I want to say that if user will select the date from start date then it will show in both fields in start date and end date also

Comment: In above snippet i show you that on form submit if end date is empty then set end date same as start date.

Comment: but last date appear when the user select start date not after click of submit button

Comment: you are taking action on submit button click. right ?

Comment: Yes. taking action on submit.

Comment: but I'm saying that when user will select the start date then it will change start date and final date also

Answer (score 0):

How about calling a function before submitting form and check if the endDate is empty or undefined. If so just set the startDate to endDate input field.

```
function beforeSubmit()
{
  if($('#endDate').val()==="" || $('#endDate').val() === undefined)
   {
    $('#endDate').val($('#startDate').val());
   }
}

<form onsubmit="return beforeSubmit()" > 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```